# Shrinking UIView with Auto Layout "breaks" the subviews

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, autolayout

I am collapsing a UIView with auto layout by setting the height constraint's constant to 0 and then calling layoutIfNeeded in the UIViewAnimation-block.
The view has many custom UIButtons as subviews and the buttons draw something in drawRect.
When the animation starts the views height gets set to 0 and all the subviews height with it. During the view scales the O hight view up, resulting in a ugly blur.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

[Sample Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_OI0NIswDmrcVlQa0JFbDB4R00/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Post your code or project for more helpful answers

Comment: @LouisTur I have just built a sample project and noticed that the problem was the AttrubuteString.
But the subview still just disappears and doesn't shrink animated